# Netbeans disabled everything & became a simple text editor when I interupted the plugin upgrade process

Tags: java, netbeans, netbeans-plugins

I switched off Netbeans while the plugins upgrade was in progress & then it has disabled everything. How do I get back everything that was available before? I've tried updating once again but it says:

`Your IDE is up to date!`

Probably it searches only for the few things remaining. It has become like a simple text editor :(

I don't want to lose my settings anyhow.. Using netbeans 7

---

## EDIT:

I see that the plugins are still installed but they have been deactivated. When I try to activate them, it fails, giving out following message:

> Activation failed: Not all requested modules can be enabled:
>   [StandardModule:org.netbeans.modules.ant.kit jarFile: C:\Program
>   Files\NetBeans 7.0\java\modules\org-netbeans-modules-ant-kit.jar,
>   StandardModule:org.netbeans.modules.form.kit jarFile: C:\Program
>   Files\NetBeans 7.0\java\modules\org-netbeans-modules-form-kit.jar,
>   StandardModule:org.netbeans.modules.versioning.system.cvss jarFile:
>   C:\Program Files\NetBeans
>   7.0\ide\modules\org-netbeans-modules-versioning-system-cvss.jar, StandardModule:org.netbeans.modules.hudson jarFile: C:\Program
>   Files\NetBeans 7.0\ide\modules\org-netbeans-modules-hudson.jar,
>   StandardModule:org.netbeans.modules.websvc.restkit jarFile: C:\Program
>   Files\NetBeans
>   7.0\enterprise\modules\org-netbeans-modules-websvc-restkit.jar, StandardModule:org.netbeans.modules.core.kit jarFile: C:\Program
>   Files\NetBeans 7.0\platform\modules\org-netbeans-modules-core-kit.jar,
>   StandardModule:org.netbeans.modules.web.primefaces jarFile: C:\Program
>   Files\NetBeans
>   7.0\enterprise\modules\org-netbeans-modules-web-primefaces.jar, StandardModule:org.netbeans.modules.apisupport.kit jarFile: C:\Program
>   Files\NetBeans
>   7.0\apisupport\modules\org-netbeans-modules-apisupport-kit.jar, StandardModule:org.netbeans.modules.subversion jarFile: C:\Program
>   Files\NetBeans 7.0\ide\modules\org-netbeans-modules-subversion.jar,
>   StandardModule:org.netbeans.modules.localhistory jarFile: C:\Program
>   Files\NetBeans 7.0\ide\modules\org-netbeans-modules-localhistory.jar,
>   StandardModule:org.netbeans.modules.spring.beans jarFile: C:\Program
>   Files\NetBeans 7.0\java\modules\org-netbeans-modules-spring-beans.jar,
>   StandardModule:org.netbeans.modules.j2ee.persistence.kit jarFile:
>   C:\Program Files\NetBeans
>   7.0\java\modules\org-netbeans-modules-j2ee-persistence-kit.jar, StandardModule:org.netbeans.modules.hibernate jarFile: C:\Program
>   Files\NetBeans 7.0\java\modules\org-netbeans-modules-hibernate.jar,
>   StandardModule:org.netbeans.modules.web.jsf.kit jarFile: C:\Program
>   Files\NetBeans
>   7.0\enterprise\modules\org-netbeans-modules-web-jsf-kit.jar, StandardModule:org.netbeans.modules.mercurial jarFile: C:\Program
>   Files\NetBeans 7.0\ide\modules\org-netbeans-modules-mercurial.jar,
>   StandardModule:org.netbeans.modules.debugger.jpda.ui jarFile:
>   C:\Program Files\NetBeans
>   7.0\java\modules\org-netbeans-modules-debugger-jpda-ui.jar, StandardModule:org.netbeans.modules.maven.kit jarFile: C:\Program
>   Files\NetBeans 7.0\java\modules\org-netbeans-modules-maven-kit.jar,
>   StandardModule:org.netbeans.modules.bugzilla jarFile: C:\Program
>   Files\NetBeans 7.0\ide\modules\org-netbeans-modules-bugzilla.jar,
>   StandardModule:org.netbeans.modules.web.kit jarFile: C:\Program
>   Files\NetBeans
>   7.0\enterprise\modules\org-netbeans-modules-web-kit.jar, StandardModule:org.netbeans.modules.java.kit jarFile: C:\Program
>   Files\NetBeans 7.0\java\modules\org-netbeans-modules-java-kit.jar,
>   StandardModule:org.netbeans.modules.ide.branding.kit jarFile:
>   C:\Program Files\NetBeans
>   7.0\nb\modules\org-netbeans-modules-ide-branding-kit.jar, StandardModule:org.netbeans.modules.spellchecker.kit jarFile:
>   C:\Program Files\NetBeans
>   7.0\ide\modules\org-netbeans-modules-spellchecker-kit.jar, StandardModule:org.netbeans.modules.web.struts jarFile: C:\Program
>   Files\NetBeans
>   7.0\enterprise\modules\org-netbeans-modules-web-struts.jar, StandardModule:org.netbeans.modules.websvc.saas.kit jarFile:
>   C:\Program Files\NetBeans
>   7.0\websvccommon\modules\org-netbeans-modules-websvc-saas-kit.jar, StandardModule:org.netbeans.modules.db.kit jarFile: C:\Program
>   Files\NetBeans 7.0\ide\modules\org-netbeans-modules-db-kit.jar,
>   StandardModule:org.netbeans.modules.profiler jarFile: C:\Program
>   Files\NetBeans 7.0\profiler\modules\org-netbeans-modules-profiler.jar,
>   StandardModule:org.netbeans.modules.websvc.kit jarFile: C:\Program
>   Files\NetBeans
>   7.0\enterprise\modules\org-netbeans-modules-websvc-kit.jar, StandardModule:org.netbeans.modules.ide.kit jarFile: C:\Program
>   Files\NetBeans 7.0\ide\modules\org-netbeans-modules-ide-kit.jar,
>   StandardModule:org.netbeans.modules.spring.webmvc jarFile: C:\Program
>   Files\NetBeans
>   7.0\enterprise\modules\org-netbeans-modules-spring-webmvc.jar, StandardModule:org.netbeans.modules.j2ee.kit jarFile: C:\Program
>   Files\NetBeans
>   7.0\enterprise\modules\org-netbeans-modules-j2ee-kit.jar]

Comment: Could you tell us if your plugins are still enabled?  Tools > Plugins > Installed (tab).  Look at the Active column to see the state of the Plugins.

Comment: @Jonathan Spooner: please see my edit..

Comment: You may need to delete your .netbeans folder. This is normally located at $USER_HOME/.netbeans. Unfortunately this folder contains all your user settings as well..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest way to fix this is to re-install NetBeans.  I don't believe that your settings have been corrupted.  So, in order to keep your settings, before you uninstall you'll need to export your settings.

1. Open Options Dialog: Tools > Options
2. Click Export button
3. Choose a location and file name to use for the zip file
4. Choose a category(s) to export

Note, that If a category is not enabled this means that you have not made any changes in that category.

If you have libraries defined and would like to save the configuration, you need to copy your build.properties file which is located in your `.netbeans` directory as exporting alone will not save this configuration (due to the fact that these settings should be able to be relocated on another machine and the libraries are specific to your machine).  In Windows, your `.netbeans` directory is located in your user directory.  For example, on my machine (Windows 7) this location is `C:\Users\Jonathan\.netbeans`.

After you've re-installed, import your settings back into the IDE and then replace the build.properties file.

Comment: Already done that! :) Anyways thanks for sharing your idea about exporting the settings, will be helpful in future!

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, after trying some thinks the following two steps solve the problem:

1. Locate the java folder, using [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16931327/where-is-the-java-sdk-folder-in-my-computer-ubuntu-12-04)
2. Run the netbeans from its folder, specifying the jdkhome with the result of the previous step:

`~/netbeans-X.X/bin/netbeans --jdkhome /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/`

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem after upgrading from java 7 to java 8. After wasting a few minutes, I discovered that netbeans wasn't seeing the right ***jdkhome***. I solved the problem in two steps:

1. In the netbeans installation folder, open the file ***netbeans.conf*** which is under ***etc*** directory. *As for my case **/home/his-kenya/netbeans-8.1/etc/netbeans.conf***
2. Set ***netbeans_jdkhome*** to point to the absolute location of your jdk. This should be on line 57 if the file hasn't been edited before. *As for my case **netbeans_jdkhome="/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0/**"*

Restart the IDE.