# Where is the Java SDK folder in my computer? Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: java, java-home

I know it's installed because when I type:

```
$java -version
```

I get:

```
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.12.5) (6b27-1.12.5-0ubuntu0.12.04.1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.0-b12, mixed mode)
```

And when I type:

```
$locate jdk
```

I get:

```
/home/arturo/Documents/2012a/sys/java/jre/glnxa64/jre/lib/servicetag/jdk_header.png
/usr/share/app-install/desktop/openjdk-6-jre:openjdk-6-java.desktop
/usr/share/app-install/desktop/openjdk-7-jre:openjdk-7-java.desktop
/usr/share/app-install/icons/openjdk-6.png
/usr/share/app-install/icons/openjdk-7.png
```

What worries me about the first item in the list is that the 2012a folder is my MATLAB folder and not a standard 'usr/lib' folder. I'm really confused on where the JDK and JRE got installed, because I need to set the $JAVA_HOME path pointing to the folder. Where am I missing something?

Comment: `java -version` doesn't tell you that you have a JDK installed. It tells you that you have a JRE installed. What does `javac -version` tell you?

Comment: Can you see if http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9612941/how-to-set-java-environment-path-in-ubuntu helps?

Comment: javac -version gives me this: javac 1.6.0_27

Comment: "Can you see if stackoverflow.com/questions/9612941/… helps?" Unfortunately it doesn't when I type $locate jvm, I don't seem to have that folder even though I'm sure its installed. EDIT: Nevermind, I found it thanks!

Answer (score 427, accepted):

> WAY-1 : Updated for the shortest and easy way

Below command will give you the path, *But it will only work if java command is working in other words if java path is configured*.

```
readlink -f $(which java)
```

Read more at [Where can I find the Java SDK in Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5251323/where-can-i-find-the-java-sdk-in-linux)

---

> WAY-2 (Better than WAY-1) : Below answer is still working and try it if above command is not working
>   for you.

You need to dig into symbolic links. Below is steps to get Java directory

Step 1:

```
$ whereis java
java: /usr/bin/java /etc/java /usr/share/java
```

That tells the command java resides in /usr/bin/java.

Dig again:

Step 2:

```
$ ls -l /usr/bin/java
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 22 2009-01-15 18:34 /usr/bin/java -> /etc/alternatives/java
```

So, now we know that `/usr/bin/java` is actually a symbolic link to `/etc/alternatives/java`.

Dig deeper using the same method above:

Step 3:

```
$ ls -l /etc/alternatives/java
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 31 2009-01-15 18:34 /etc/alternatives/java -> /usr/local/jre1.6.0_07/bin/java
```

So, thats the actual location of java: `/usr/local/jre.....`

You could still dig deeper to find other symbolic links.

---

Reference : [where is java's home dir?](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1054731)

Answer (score 161):

Please use this command:

```
readlink -f $(which java)
```

It works for me with Ubuntu gnome.

On my computer the result is:

> /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/bin/java

Regards.

Answer (score 35):

In generally, java gets installed at **/usr/lib/jvm** . That is where my sun jdk is installed. check if it is same for open jdk also.

Answer (score 12):

```
$whereis java
java: /usr/bin/java /usr/bin/X11/java /usr/share/java     /usr/share/man/man1/java.1.gz
$cd /usr/bin
$ls -l java
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 22 Apr 15  2014 java -> /etc/alternatives/java
$ls -l /etc/alternatives/java
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 39 Apr 15  2014 /etc/alternatives/java ->     /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/bin/java
```

So,JDK's real location is  `/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/`

Answer (score 7):

Location of JRE in Ubuntu:

/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre

Answer (score 6):

$ whereis java

java: /usr/bin/java /usr/lib/java /usr/bin/X11/java /usr/share/java   /usr/share/man/man1/java.1.gz

Answer (score 5):

On Ubuntu 14.04, it is in `/usr/lib/jvm/default-java`.

Answer (score 3):

For me, on Ubuntu, the various versions of JDK were in `/usr/lib/jvm`.

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution to this with path name: 
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle

I'm on mint 18.1

Answer (score 2):

I am using Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS. In my case I had to open the file:

```
/home/[username]/netbeans-8.2/etc/netbeans.conf
```

And change the jdk location to:

```
netbeans_jdkhome="/opt/jdk/jdk1.8.0_152"
```

Then saved the file and re-run Netbeans. It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

you can simply write the following command in the terminal of your linux system and get the java path :- `echo $JAVA_HOME`

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do so is by typing `echo $JAVA_HOME` on your terminal.