# Error: JAVA_HOME is not defined correctly ubuntu

Tags: java, ubuntu-12.04

i have used  this command but not working

```
export JAVA_HOME=:/usr/bin/java
```

show error message:

```
    Error: JAVA_HOME is not defined correctly.
  We cannot execute :/usr/bin/java/bin/java
```

Answer (score 3):

`JAVA_HOME` must be set to a directory that contains a `bin` sub-directory with a `java` executable in it.
In general, it is set to the root directory of a JDK or JRE. If you want to use the "system" java, set `JAVA_HOME` to `/usr` (and don't put a colon after the =):

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr
```

Comment: nice simple and easies solution :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle
```

or

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_05
```

In this one, you need to rename `jdk1.8.0_05` depending on the installed path on your system.

Comment: $ ant debug $   use this command show again error                                          Error: JAVA_HOME is not defined correctly.
 We cannot execute :/usr/bin/java

Comment: I just added two more possible options. You need to go to your usr folder, see if there is a java folder, if so, if inside that folder there is a jdk folder, then use the third one.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, you set such paths in ~/.bashrc.

Findout where is java location in your ubuntu machine. For help, check this: [Where is the Java SDK folder in my computer? Ubuntu 12.04](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16931327/where-is-the-java-sdk-folder-in-my-computer-ubuntu-12-04)

after that add export line to your ~/.bashrc file

```
export JAVA_HOME=....
```

Comment: how to open my ~/.bashrc file?

Comment: bash: export: `/usr/bin/X11/java': not a valid identifier
bash: export: `/usr/share/java': not a valid identifier
bash: export: `/usr/share/man/man1/java.1.gz': not a valid identifier

Comment: `~` points to your home directory which can be something like `/home/angu`. So the bashrc path will be `/home/angu/.bashrc`

Comment: From the link I provided, check where is your Java installation path. Also verify if java is properly installed with command `java -version`. If not, re-install java.