# echo $JAVA_HOME returns nothing

Tags: java

How to get the java home dir?

When doing this

```
echo $JAVA_HOME
```

Nothing is returned

[image]

Comment: The answer is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24641536/how-to-set-java-home-in-linux-for-all-users

Answer (score 46):

You need to set the $JAVA_HOME variable

**In my case while setting up Maven, I had to set it up to where JDK is installed.**

First find out where JAVA is installed:

```
$ whereis java
java: /usr/bin/java /usr/share/java /usr/share/man/man1/java.1.gz
```

Now dig deeper-

```
$ ls -l /usr/bin/java
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 46 Aug 25  2016 /etc/alternatives/java -> /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java
```

Dig deeper:

```
$ ls -l /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 6464 Mar 14 18:28 /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java
```

As it is not being referenced to any other directory, we'll use this.

Open /etc/environment using nano

`$ sudo nano /etc/environment`

Append the following lines

```
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64
export JAVA_HOME
```

Reload PATH using `$ . /etc/environment`

Now,
`$ echo $JAVA_HOME`

Here is your output:

`/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64`

Sources I referred to:

https://askubuntu.com/a/175519

https://stackoverflow.com/a/23427862/6297483

Comment: Excellent answer. I know the original poster didn't mark your answer as correct, but the detailed instructions worked for me. Thank you.

Comment: does not work, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24641536/how-to-set-java-home-in-linux-for-all-users has the correct answer

Comment: Upon reboot, the /etc/environment variables are NOT loaded. This is not a workable solution.

Answer (score 9):

`$JAVA_HOME` is a global variable that you typically must set yourself.

In certain (most?) platforms, installing Java will not set your `JAVA_HOME` variable.

The advantage here is that you can have multiple Java versions co-existing within one system.

Since you're running on *nix system, you can do that in your own logon scripts, such as `~/.bashrc` or `~/.bash_profile`, etc.

Comment: In macOS Ventura, it's ~/.zprofile

Answer (score 4):

If the terminal is `zsh` and not `bash` then we need to set JAVA_HOME in either of these files `~/.zshenv` or `~/.zshrc` [more details about zsh terminal here](https://sourabhbajaj.com/mac-setup/iTerm/zsh.html)

steps:

- run this command in the terminal `open ~/.zshrc`
- in the zshrc file append java_home path (refer below two lines)
- `export JAVA_HOME="/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-x.x.x.jdk/Contents/Home"`
- `export PATH="$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH"}`
- re-launch zsh terminal
- In the zsh terminal run this command `echo $JAVA_HOME`

Comment: In macOS Ventura, it's ~/.zprofile

Comment: It worked, Thanks !

Answer (score 3):

1. Open your terminal, and open your .bash_profile file by executing:

   nano ~/.bash_profile

(If it is the first time, it should be empty)
2.  Ad an echo message just to see a greeting message by pasting

```
echo "Hello, Your Bash Profile Is Running…"
```

Type: ctrl + x  to exit from nano
Type:  Y           to save change and press enter

3. In order to get the message to appear every time we open a terminal execute:
   source ~/.bash_profile
4. In the file ~/.bash_profile, set the $JAVA_HOME environment variable by adding the
   following to the end of the file:

   export JAVA_HOME="/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk13.jdk/Contents/Home"
   export PATH="$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH"

Type: ctrl + x  to exit from nano
Type:  Y           to save change and press enter

5. Close and reopen your terminal to update the environment variables.
6. Verify JAVA_HOME by executing echo $JAVA_HOME.

Source: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0gceUrMnjzo

Comment: In macOS Ventura, it's ~/.zprofile

Answer (score 1):

If you are using latest versions of OS, then you cannot use ~/.bash_profile to export your environment variable since bash shell is deprecated in the latest version of OS.

This answer may give you the exact solution:https://stackoverflow.com/a/62192114/3962688

Answer (score 0):

What solved to me, using Ubuntu 18, was removing java from /etc/profile

So, export JAVA_HOME=/usr/bin

Answer (score 0):

after saving JAVA_HOME in enviroment file

$ source /etc/environment
$ echo  $JAVA_HOME

this worked for me

Answer (score -2):

set it first?

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/bin/java
```

See more here:

[How to set JAVA_HOME in Linux for all users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24641536/how-to-set-java-home-in-linux-for-all-users)

Comment: I think JAVA_HOME should be till the java folder not java/bin