# Failing to install Java8 in Ubuntu: Command Not Found/E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Tags: java, linux, ubuntu

I am trying to install Java 8 in Ubuntu but I am failing to do it. I tried the following commands to install it:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
```

After completion of this, I triggered the command javac -version.

[This is the error log which i got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/axpv4.png)

Comment: Tried to figure out the problem with the command: sudo dpkg --aduit | more. Ubuntu hinted out: For the first time it was partially configured. So i removed the listed items and again i tried installing it but still the same problem persists.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this thread](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2374686) , there was a problem on WebUpd8's side. This link [here](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2374686&page=4&p=13731177#post13731177) will give you the commands as a temporary solution.
If the problem still persits, you can download it manually.
Download link is [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/pt/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html), and the instructions are [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/install/linux_jdk.html).

Comment: Installed successfully!!

Comment: I have extracted in the /opt directory. And installation is also successful. And to check the version just i wrote: javac -version and java -version and it worked. Additionally i used: update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/java java /opt/jdk/jdk1.8.0_05/bin/java 100 along with update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/javac javac /opt/jdk/jdk1.8.0_05/bin/javac 100. But when i typed echo $JAVA_HOME it's \showing nothing.

Comment: This query has already been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35752497/echo-java-home-returns-nothing). If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.

Comment: Thanks i got the solution. (Accepted)