# jvm path not found on mac

Tags: java, jvm

I have installed java11 using

```
brew install java11
```

Then I tried the below to get JAVA_HOME

```
echo $JAVA_HOME
```

It returned empty .
so following the instructions in [echo $JAVA_HOME returns nothing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35752497/echo-java-home-returns-nothing)

when I have run `ls -l /usr/bin/java`
i cannot see any jvm path as shown in the above link. Below is what I got

```
 ~ % ls -l /usr/bin/java
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  168432 Dec  8 05:09 /usr/bin/java

ls -l /usr/lib/jvm/
ls: /usr/lib/jvm/: No such file or directory
```

How to set JAVA_HOME

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using bash, all you have to do is:

```
echo export "JAVA_HOME=\$(/usr/libexec/java_home)" >> ~/.bash_profile
```

If you're using zsh (which probably means you're running macOS Catalina or newer), then it should instead be:

```
echo export "JAVA_HOME=\$(/usr/libexec/java_home)" >> ~/.zshrc
```

In either case, restart your shell.

If you have multiple JDK versions installed and you want it to be a specific one, you can use the -v flag to java_home like so:

```
echo export "JAVA_HOME=\$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.7)" >> ~/.bash_profile
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me. When I source the `.bash_profile` after your first command, I get this error: `The operation couldn't be completed. Unable to locate a Java Runtime. Please visit http://www.java.com for information on installing Java.` But I have installed java via `brew install openjdk@11`. And `which java` yields a correct path. Any ideas?

Comment: I'm thinking a version of openjdk that runs on M1 might be needed?