# Can't find JDK location in Ubuntu

Tags: java

I know this is silly, but I've installed Oracle's Java 8 JDK long time ago, and I'm trying to setup my intelliJ Idea IDE to fetch the JDK, the problem is I can't figure out where is it exactly located.
I've tried using `$whereis java` and `$readlink -f $(which java)` , but they all point to the JRE not to the JDK.
My `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle` folder doesn't have a JDK folder, and `$JAVA_HOME` points to the path mentioned above.
I'm sure that I have a JDK as I am able to javac any .java file, but I don't really know where the JDK is.
I've looked at different answers on SO, but none of them seems to solve my silly problem.

Any ideas?

Update: I tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16931327/where-is-the-java-sdk-folder-in-my-computer-ubuntu-12-04) but it still points me to the JRE location.

Comment: Have you tried `whereis javac`?

Comment: @AxelH - it seems the OP has already done what the answers to that duplicate are suggesting to do, but only finds a JRE, not a JDK. I wouldn't vote as a duplicate in this case.

Comment: @AxelH I tried this answer but it didn't work also for me (the readlink part)

Comment: @RealSkeptic yup, it also shows '/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/javac'  but still no JDK folder.
also bin doesn't have a JDK folder, only a JRE folder

Comment: It seems that the java-8-oracle folder itself should be the JDK folder. If there is a javac in a bin directory, then that bin directory is in a JDK (there is always also a JRE inside any JDK). What are you missing?

Comment: If it was me, at this point i would've just reinstalled the JDK

Comment: @RealSkeptic, I agree about the tries done but there is some path there that could be check. `/usr/local/` from example. The `whereis javac` is in comment there too. There is not only the accepted answer to check there.

Comment: Well, there is always solution to do a search on the full partition to find the javac file or any other...

Comment: @RealSkeptic IntelliJ refuses to consider that folder as the JDK location, I think I am going to reinstall the JDK again.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16931327/where-is-the-java-sdk-folder-in-my-computer-ubuntu-12-04?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: [Where is the Java SDK folder in my computer? Ubuntu 12.04](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16931327/where-is-the-java-sdk-folder-in-my-computer-ubuntu-12-04?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: @AxelH I am doing a clean install, you can close the question. Thanks!