# Setting java SDK for IntelliJ project

Tags: java, intellij-idea, sdk, java-8, ubuntu-16.04

So I have a java project that I opened using IntelliJ. However I am getting the following error

`cannot resolve symbol string`

I checked **file->project_structure** and found that the project SDK is invalid

[image]

So I tried to add java sdk to the project. I followed the instruction mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16931327/where-is-the-java-sdk-folder-in-my-computer-ubuntu-12-04) and found that my SDK path is

`/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java`

However when I try to add and SDK using that link I get the following error message

[image]

I am not sure I understand where is the problem .. any suggestions ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're pointing IntelliJ IDEA to the "bin" directory of the JDK's JRE, while IntelliJ IDEA wants you to specify the "home" directory of the JDK. The valid path would be `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64`